# I'm using ubuntu 12.04 lts .The command sudo fdisk-1 gets a response "command not found" .Is this command no longer valid?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to transfer some apps and files to a zip drive. I need to mount the device and sudo fdisk-1 was the first step. I also tried a cd but that didn't work either.

Comment: "fdisk-1" has never been a command. You probably meant "fdisk -l" (mind the space and the l not a 1)

Answer (score 2):

The command is `fdisk -l`. You need a space after `fdisk` and it's a lower case <kbd>L</kbd>, not a <kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: and it is a small "L" and not the number one

Comment: Could you please review my edits and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future.